# How to use mmioWrite in .NET?

Tags: c#, audio, vb6, wav

I am trying to port the VB6 statement below to C# and I can't figure out how to properly get the pointer to the WAVEFORMATEX struct to be used with the mmioWrite function. Any ideas?

```vb
'write format chunk
mmioWrite(hmmioOut, VarPtr(WFX), Len(WFX))
```

Comment: Just write another pinvoke declaration for the function, now making the 2nd argument `ref WaveFormatEx` instead of IntPtr.

Comment: Thanks Hans, it worked as you suggested.